# Why is the NMR result for my p-toluic acid product so odd?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

I just started learning about NMR and did a lab session where we conducted Grignard rxn with CO2 to form p-toluic acid and my NMR result is:

1H NMR (400 MHz, CDCl3) δ 9.63 (s, 4H), 8.07 – 8.00 (m, 5H), 8.01 (s, 1H), 7.34 – 7.22 (m, 5H), 2.46 (s, 6H).

I should expect a peak around 12ppm which would signify the presence of a COOH group; however, I got a broad peak at 9.63ppm with the integration of 4H. It doesn't make sense and I did a melting point analysis to also check the identity of the product. The melting point for my product (175°C -178°C ) is quite close to the literature range(177°C -180°C ). The range is a little off but it could be due to the product not being dried enough. Ultimately, I can't explain why I'm not getting a peak around 12ppm. Could it be due to side products?

Comment: This is very clearly not p-toluic acid. Where is the Me group 3H singlet?

Comment: It seems that I made an error for the chemical shift. It should be 2.46ppm(s, 6H). My guess why its 6H and not 3H is that there might be side products and the chemical shifts for the methyl groups on the main and side products have around the same chemical shifts. I'm not sure about my reasoning. As for the 9.36ppm, it's lower than what I expected. However, from the melting point analysis, I'm certain I did manage to synthesize p-toluic acid, albeit being slightly impure.

Comment: What starting material did you use? p-bromo-toluene?

Comment: The shift of the acidic proton can be very variable, as can its integration. For this reason it is rarely diagnostic. One possible byproduct is the dimethyl biphenyl

Comment: I only know that I was given an aryl bromide with the formula C7H7Br to react with Mg to get the Grignard reagent and then react with CO2 to get the carboxylic acid portion. But I think it should p-bromo-toluene. My TA told me the final product should be p-toluic acid.

Comment: My guess is that some water could have entered during the formation of the Grignard reagent...that's the only reason I can think of to explain the results

Comment: ooo i see...dimethyl phenyl...could it be that some of the unreacted grignard reagent could've reacted with the starting reagent?

Comment: Grignards can dimerise under some conditions

Comment: If your dry ice isn't really dry (it might look dry, but there might be water on the surface) then that will give you a fair bit of protonation product. In this case that's toluene so you may be able to get rid of it with a good vacuum.

Comment: Part of the reason you're confused is that you're picking a bad signal to be your reference peak for integration. Integrations in NMR spectra are *relative* values - you always have to "define" the value for the integral of your first signal, and all other integrals are based relative to that. If you select a bad signal for your first integral, it'll mess up the rest of the analysis. Assuming there is only one clean sharp signal in the alkyl region and that it is a singlet, you should set that integral to 3.00 and see how the other integrals change.

Comment: If you took advantage of the base solubility of p-toluic acid during workup, you would have answered the question of whether or not you have a carboxylic acid or non-acidic product. If not, you should have.